# Closing and region filling

Tags: image-processing

Main functions that closing performs are :

```
fills gaps
eliminates holes
And removes pepper noise.
```

For the purpose of region filling there is an algorithm available. The main formula for it is:

```
dilate(image, structure element) intersection (complement of image).
```

My question is why can we simply not use closing if it can fill the gaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you must use the intersection is because it is possible that when dilating, the shape as you are region filling can extend **beyond** the perimeter of the shape.  If you recall the region filling algorithm, you start off at an initial seed point that is usually set to the centre of mass of the object.  We will denote this as the initial region grown object.  Then, for each non-zero pixel in the region grown object, you dilate around that point.  This continues until the region grown object matches in size with the actual shape you are trying to region fill itself and thus you extract out the object of interest that results from region growing.

You **must** use the intersection to ensure that the region filled object conforms to the same shape as the object itself.  Intersecting the region filled object with the shape itself will remove the areas that are not common with the shape and the region filled object at a particular iteration or else you would basically fill the entire screen with white.

You don't use closing because that's not what region filling is for.  Remember that the point is to isolate out objects from an image given a known seed point.  Simply performing morphological closing does not accomplish that for you as it applies to the entire image.  You only want to extract out an object where an initial point internally in the object is known.